# Get list of cached images

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using the library picasso to load a collection of images from the web into my app.

```
Picasso.with(this).load(url.getString(url.getColumnIndex(mediaURL))+media.getString(0));
```

How can I get a list of the cached images by picasso?
How long will the images be in cache until I will have to load them again?

Answer (score 3):

Picasso does not support disk caching by itself.

It uses a memory cache, which lives as long as your application does, and targets about 15% of the available space on the heap.

For the disk cache, it relies on the HTTP client you're using. For example, if you're using it with OkHttp, the disk cache size is 50 MB most of the times (they target 2% of disk space, within a range of 5-50MB).

So, the images will leave the cache once full (a DiskLruCache is used, meaning the least recently used images in the cache get removed first) but you have no control over that.

If you need access to the images, you could pass in a custom Cache file location and size when initialising Picasso:

new Picasso.Builder.with(context).downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(cacheFile, cacheSize)).build();

Later you can access the cache file and images at any time.